How to solve Mojo SDK initialization error in VScode?
I installed Max and Mojo, and set up the path correctly, and Mojo works just fine in both Ubuntu wsl and VScode. However, each time I start up VScode, the below message persists:
"Mojo SDK initialization error: The mojo.modularHomePath setting '/home/myusername/.modular' does not exist."
I ignore it and go on normally, but I don't understand why it shows up?!
I tried updating and even reinstalling mojo
I made sure the path to the MODULAR_HOME containing the Mojo SDK installation, is set to /home/myusername/.modular

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
